# How to change the selected table row background using Material-UI on React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use the React and Material-UI. In this question, the selected table row background is inherited from muiTheme borderColor defaultly. But If I overwrite the borderColor, it will effect to other element :( So, How to only change the table row background selected.

Comment: How about add a specific `className` for selected row and tweak it through CSS ?

Comment: @FiriceNguyen: Yes, it's a useful method. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  tableRow: {
    backgroundColor: "green !important",
  },
}));

 const classes = useStyles();
<TableRow classes={{root: classes.tableRow,}}/>
```